# jquery removeAttr('id') vz. removeProp('id')

Tags: javascript, jquery

can somebody explains me how to remove id from element in right way?
I thought that jQ prop() is new prefered form of attr() and removeProp() as well.
But if i try to remove id by removeProp('id') jQ sets the id of element to id='undefined'. It produces the elements with id='undefined'(as I see in debuger) and I don't think it is corect. ID should be unique on the page. Shouldn't it?
RemoveAttr() removes the id from the element as I expect(it means element have not id as I see in debuger). But I am not sure what is the corect way to do it?
Can you explain it?
Thanks!

Comment: *"I thought that jQ prop() is new prefered form of attr() and removeProp() as well"* -- well, you thought wrong. `.prop()` should be used for properties and `.attr()` for attributes. The id is an attribute so you should use `.removeAttr()`.

Comment: Ok thanks I have it. ID is an attribute not property. Thanks.

Comment: @Juhana There are both an [`id` content attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute) and an [`id` IDL attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#dom-element-id) (a.k.a property). The second one reflect the first.

Answer (score 1):

I think the confusion comes from before jQuery 1.6, in which the `.attr()` function sometimes would take property values into account before retrieving attributes. This was inconsistent behavior. As of jQuery 1.6 `.prop()` explicitly retrieves property values and `.attr()` explicitly attributes.

What is odd, still, is that `.prop()` accepts elements' `disabled` attribute as valid. The `disabled` feat of elements is seen as an **attribute** not a property.

Among this, yes, you should be using `.removeAttr()` to remove the `id` attribute. Not `.removeProp()`

Comment: Ok thanks I have it. ID is an attribute not property. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between `attr` and `prop` is easy: the first one gets or sets content attributes (a.k.a attributes), and the second one gets or sets IDL attributes (a.k.a properties).

When there are an attribute and a property with the same name, `prop` is usually preferred because it shows the current state of the element.

For example, the `value` property of an `input` element is its current value. Its `value` attribute is its the initial value (that's the same as the `defaultValue` property).

Note this is not the case of `id`, because the property [reflects](http://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#concept-reflect) the attribute, so they always are the same.

When you want to delete, it's different. You can remove attributes freely, but properties are non-deletable. That's because those properties are implemented as inherited getters/setters, but only own properties can be deleted.

```js
var el = document.createElement('div');
el.id = 'foo';
el.hasOwnProperty('id'); // false
delete el.id; // Does not delete
el.id; // "foo"
```

In jQuery 1, `deleteProp` was implemented like

```js
removeProp: function( name ) {
  name = jQuery.propFix[ name ] || name;
  return this.each(function() {
    // try/catch handles cases where IE balks (such as removing a property on window)
    try {
      this[ name ] = undefined;
      delete this[ name ];
    } catch( e ) {}
  });
}
```

Therefore, the `id` became `"undefined"` because of `this[ name ] = undefined;`.

In jQuery 2 they changed that to

```js
removeProp: function( name ) {
  return this.each(function() {
    delete this[ jQuery.propFix[ name ] || name ];
  });
}
```

Therefore, now `deleteProp('id')` does not alter the `id`.

So if you want to remove the `id`, better remove the attribute.

Comment: Thanks, so id attribute reflects the id property unlike the value attr. which reflects the defaultValue. And implentation in jQ of removeProp cant remove the id cause it is an attribute. I found this article about delete operator https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete but its quite dificult to imagine how it works with id attr of elements. I think id is an variable in function which produces the element object. But i am not js killer only poor  user.

Comment: Or attributes are the part of element.prototype which can be deleted only by delete el.prototype.id?

Comment: @Čamo `id` is defined as a getter and a setter in `Element.prototype` (`HTMLElement.prototype` on IE). You can use `delete Element.prototype.id` to remove them, but then you will no longer be able to use the `id` property to read or write the ID of any element; and the internal ID data will still be there, accessible through the `id` attribute.